# Tkinter widget.place() does not work

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create and open multiple windows on Tkinter. I am facing a problem with using the widget.pack(). What I don't understand is that, if I use widget.pack() instead, it works perfectly fine but It's not appearing on the screen like how I want it to. Hence, I want to use the .place() function.

*My code looks something like:*

```
class GroupFrame(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    global memList
    global rootHome
    self.master.geometry("400x500")
    self.master.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    self.master.title("PowerPuff Chat Girls")

    #TextArea
    self.ChatLog = Text(self, bd=0, bg="light grey", height="13", width="55", font="Arial")
    self.ChatLog.insert(END, 'Welcome to the PowerPuff Chat, ' + username + '\n', 'INIT')
    self.ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
    self.ChatLog.tag_config('INIT', foreground='red', justify=CENTER)
    self.ChatLog.tag_config('BLUE', foreground='blue', justify=LEFT)
    self.ChatLog.tag_config('BLK', foreground='black', justify=RIGHT)

    #ScrollBar
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, command = self.ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
    self.ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set

    #EntryBox
    self.EntryBox = Text(self, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")

    #SendButton
    self.SendButton = Button(self, font=30, text="Send", width="11", height=1,
                        bg="white", fg='navy blue', activebackground="#FACC2E")
        -------------------THIS PART -------------------
    #Place them on Screen
    self.scrollbar.place(x=380, y=6, height=386)
    self.ChatLog.place(x=8, y=6, height=405, width=370)
    self.EntryBox.place(x=128, y=425, height=60, width=248)
    self.SendButton.place(x=6, y=425, height=60)
    .
    .
```

*Where I create a new window of this class: (from another class)*

```
    .
    .
    def _go_group(self):
        global check, do
        check = 1
        self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.pf = GroupFrame(self.newWindow)
```

Can someone please spot any error or tell me If I am missing something? 
Where am I going wrong?

When I run the code with widget.pack():
It's basically blank. None of the widgets seem to appear on the window.
[image]

Comment: Please specify does not work

Comment: @abccd thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the post. Please check again now

Comment: If you want to increase chances of someone's help in debugging - please, make your code runnable.

Comment: By the way, I just changed parent of you widgets from `self` to `self.master` (TopLevel) and it looks like it's works [as you expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahhcI.png). So take care of how you declare your class.

Comment: I suspect that you just forgot to place your `self` (Frame) in a `self.master` (Toplevel), if you add, for example, `self.place(height=1000, width=1000)` line immediately after where you placed your widgets - it's would works too.

Comment: we don't need code "something like" your code. We need _minimal_ code that actually reproduces the problem. It would also help if you explained which widget you're referring to. I see lots of widgets, but none of them are named "widget".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted, which is rather incomplete, The problem isn't with calling `pack` or `place` inside the widget. It appears you simply aren't calling `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on `self.pf`. If `self.pf` isn't visible, nothing inside `self.pf` will be visible.

You need to add the last line in the following example:

```
self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
self.pf = GroupFrame(self.newWindow)
self.pf.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```